# How do I insert a line break using Google Sheets API?

Tags: unicode, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use a line break in Google Sheets. If I want a cell to show this:

**Over
Under**

What do I put inside the `set.Value()` method?

I am trying this:

```
function myFunction(cell){
  cell.setValue('Over
                 Under')
  }
```

Does not work....

**UPDATE:**
I have also tried this

```
cell.setValue(otherCell.getValue());
```

This seems to work as long as **otherCell** is the value I want. I can't figure out how to inspect this element though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using "\n", to insert a new line into a text cell.

and example would be:

`cell.setValue("Over"+"\n"+"Under");`

Yields:

Over
Under

It works pretty well for situations where you are appending the contents of a cell:

`cell.setValue(cell.getValue()+"\n"+"Updated info");`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using **String.charCodeAt()**, it seems that the 'line break' has a unicode value of 10.

```
cell.setValue('Over'+String.fromCharCode(10)+'Under')
```

yields a single cell with

**Over
Under**